# Rows to columns in access writing sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

I want to create 2 new columns with a query, `name` and `amount`.

After that insert my current column names and values to these 2 columns.

Please find a screenshot of what I have and what I need to have.

Here is what I have for the 2 lines I have. Can somebody help me to transform these to the form I need?

```sql
select 0 as mobile
           ,sum(b.R1001) as R1001
           ,sum(b.R1002) as R1002
           ,0 as other
           ,sum(b.mds) as mds
           ,sum(b.m2m) as m2m
           ,sum(b.fixed) as fixed
           ,sum(b.C1001) as C1001
           ,sum(b.C2001) as C2001
           ,sum(b.C2003) as C2003
           ,sum(b.C3003) as C3003 
from (
SELECT  
            iif(a.account_id like 'R1001', Sum(x.amount), 0) as R1001
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'R1002', Sum(x.amount), 0) as R1002
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'R1004' and x.hfm_classification like 'mds', Sum(x.amount), 0) as mds
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'R1004' and x.hfm_classification like 'm2m', Sum(x.amount), 0) as m2m
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'R1004' and x.hfm_classification like 'fixed', Sum(x.amount), 0) as fixed
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'C1001', Sum(x.amount), 0) as C1001
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'C2001', Sum(x.amount), 0) as C2001
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'C2003', Sum(x.amount), 0) as C2003
            ,iif(a.account_id like 'C3003', Sum(x.amount), 0) as C3003
FROM tbl_account AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_input AS t INNER JOIN tbl_cid AS C ON c.cid = t.cid WHERE c.segment like 'VGE')  AS x ON x.account = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_id IN ('R1001', 'R1002', 'R1004', 'C1001', 'C2001', 'C2003', 'C3003')
GROUP BY a.account_id, t.hfm_classification
) b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use `union all`.  Do be careful about the types, though, if the columns are not all strings:

```
select 'mobile' as name, mobile as amount
from t
union all
select 'R1001', R1001
from t
union all
. . .
```

Because your data is generated by a query, you might want to turn that into a view for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks!

Can you advise on why I am getting error on creating a view for this?

create view vge_calculation as (
*code above*)

Comment: @Looz ... No.  `UNION ALL` should be allowed in views.  Be sure all the columns have names.